# Permission error when starting workspace on Laradock Docker on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Each time when starting `docker-compose up` on Laradock, receives Permission error for workspace laradock on Windows 10. I have tried restarting but not working.

```sh
PS D:\projects\sites\laradock> docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace
laradock_redis_1 is up-to-date
laradock_mysql_1 is up-to-date
laradock_docker-in-docker_1 is up-to-date
laradock_phpmyadmin_1 is up-to-date
Starting laradock_workspace_1 ... error

ERROR: for laradock_workspace_1  Cannot start service workspace: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint laradock_workspace_1 (cc289cd2758bb1c99d3f8aab7243220a94078e19b2a1f4a08e4b0b01fbba64a3): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2222: unexpected error Permission denied

ERROR: for workspace  Cannot start service workspace: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint laradock_workspace_1 (cc289cd2758bb1c99d3f8aab7243220a94078e19b2a1f4a08e4b0b01fbba64a3): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2222: unexpected error Permission denied
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0: 2222, your host os already run service bind port 2222.

Comment: You can change in mapping port in .env file.

Comment: Then try running `docker-compose down` to clean up containers and networks, then up again and see if that fixes things.

Comment: can you please give me your `docker-compose --version`

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1038

Comment: docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

Comment: See [how you can find out which process is listening on a port on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your answer [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1804) .In short you should execute this command `netcfg -d` this will clean up all networking devices, and requires a reboot

Comment: follow the link in my answer , users with similar issue pointed to this method as an answer.